# Facebook Page: How to choose who can see your post and who can't

Tags: facebook-pages

In Facebook personal account, there is a feature to choose your audience by selecting `Who should see this?` option as shown below?

Image from https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/guide-facebook-symbols/
[image]

Is there a way to do the same in Facebook page?

I don't want to block those users, but trying to limit what they can see as they tend to spam and post unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can restrict the visibility of the posts in a Facebook page. However, you can control if visitors can post directly to the page from the page settings.

You should be able to see the **Settings** button on the top right corner when you are on the Page. Choose *Edit* corresponding to **Visitor posts** and choose if the posts should be reviewed before published on the page.

You can also choose to enable the **Profanity Filter** or/and enable blocking of certain words by using **Page moderation** option.

[image]